# Spring Boot app not starting

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application which was running fine. I just added another column in table and specified it in entity. Now I am running it and the application getting stuck at one point and not starting. It seems to be a Hibernate issue with Spring Boot. Following are the logs:

```
Nov 18, 2016 8:45:53 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: default
        ...]
Nov 18, 2016 8:45:54 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.9.Final}
Nov 18, 2016 8:45:54 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Nov 18, 2016 8:45:54 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Nov 18, 2016 8:45:54 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Nov 18, 2016 8:45:56 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
Nov 18, 2016 8:45:58 PM org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator configure
WARN: HHH90000014: Found use of deprecated [org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator] sequence-based id generator;
Nov 18, 2016 8:46:00 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator validate
INFO: HHH000229: Running schema validator
Nov 18, 2016 8:46:13 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
```

Comment: Where are the errors ? Can you post all the logs ?

Comment: Not getting any error. If you can notice the last line in logs is "ASTQueryTranslatorFactory". Application startup is stuck at this point and I waited for even more than 40 minutes. I have no idea how to debug this problem.

Comment: Ok. So, enable the logger to the trace level.  It could tell you with more precision where exactly the server blocks. Here, we have not less than INFO level. You can also make a thread dump when it is blocked to analyse what your threads does. It could give you some clues. Use jstack to do that :
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html